# Individual percentage for each item, throughput

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

With the following code I get how many items that is not "Out", but it returns percentage for all the items and not for each individual. I know it has to do with the count(date) that counts all the date of the all the unitids. Is there any way to count each item individual so it doesn't show the total percentage?

```
SELECT unitid, (COUNT(date)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items)) AS Percentage
FROM items
WHERE date !='Out'
GROUP BY unitid
```

EDIT1, clarification: Lets say I have 2 of each product, product a, b, c, d and e, one of each item is 'Out'. The result I get is:

```
    unitid    Percentage
1.  a         10
2.  b         10
3.  c         10
4.  d         10
5.  e         10
```

I'd like it to show this instead:

```
    unitid    Percentage
1.  a         50
2.  b         50
3.  c         50
4.  d         50
5.  e         50
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please show some sample data explaining the problem and the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *link* between the count items and the item selected.

```
SELECT
   unitid,
   COUNT(date) * 100
      / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items B WHERE B.unidid = A.unitid) AS Percentage
FROM items A
WHERE date !='Out'
GROUP BY unitid
```

Comment: This answer is not best because it has to join two tables. See [Gordon Linoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14071968/57611) for how to do it in a single table scan. This also will only give integer percentages (such as `33`). To return decimal percentages with fractions such as `33.33333` use `* 100.0`.

Comment: It was a bit Q&D I admit but the result is correct. Gordons queries don't filter on date = 'out' so it won't result in a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You query does not require a subquery, just a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT i.unitid, 100*sum(case when date <> 'Out' then 1 else 0 end)/count(date) as Percentage
FROM items i
GROUP BY unitid
```

Assuming that [date] is never NULL, you express this more simply as:

```
select i.unitid, 100*avg(case when date<>'out' then 1.0 else 0 end) as Percentage
from items i
group by unitid
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The OP's [selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14069495/57611) is not best because it has to perform a join, but this query will do a single scan.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand this correctly. If you have one a, two b, three c, and four d's, one of each is "Out", whatever that is, your result set should be:

```
    unitid    Percentage
1.  a         100.00
2.  b         50.00
3.  c         33.33
4.  d         25.00
```

To do that, you can try this:

```
Select counts.unitId, 100.0 *outcounts.count/ counts.count  as Percentage
from (select unitid, count(*) as count 
        from items 
        where items.date ='Out' 
        group by unitid) as outcounts
  inner join (select unitid, count(*) as count 
              from items 
              group by unitid) as counts
    on outcounts.unitId = counts.unitId
```

here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/281c1/13) with the setup